# stack image and span tag next to each other - bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to align both `image` tag and `p span` tag next to each other. And I do not want to put them in two different div's to follow the grid system as then it doesn't give me the correct final output that I desire.

Here is my small piece of code that I want to correct: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/axknnm5t/)

```
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3" style="padding-right:0px">
            <img src="Images/signin_logo.jpg" width="150" height="110" />
            <p> <span style="color:#989898; font-size:36px">Template Fire Sign In</span>
                <br /> <span style="color:#A8A8A8; font-size:18px">Please sign in with your credentials now to get access.</span>

            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/axknnm5t/)

I want the `<p>` tag next to the image tag.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/axknnm5t/1/ like this? p is block element, by default... you can add inline-block value to display property, in this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options

```css
.row p {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3" style="padding-right:0px">
            <img src="Images/signin_logo.jpg" width="150" height="110" />
            <p> <span style="color:#989898; font-size:36px">Template Fire Sign In</span>
                <br /> <span style="color:#A8A8A8; font-size:18px">Please sign in with your credentials now to get access.</span>

            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

or

```css
.row img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3" style="padding-right:0px">
            <img src="Images/signin_logo.jpg" width="150" height="110" />
            <p> <span style="color:#989898; font-size:36px">Template Fire Sign In</span>
                <br /> <span style="color:#A8A8A8; font-size:18px">Please sign in with your credentials now to get access.</span>

            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply this css --

```
img, p {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

This will make the img and p tag to be next to each other, as long as both element's width doesn't cross the container's width.